# Python String item not callable/math

Tags: python, error-handling, callable

I have to write a program that given the number below, s, finds the maximum product of a given length of consecutive numbers within the larger number. I have the framework of the code but in the line preceded by the three "#"s i keep getting an error that I cant call string 's' even though I'm turning it into an integer. I kind of understand why but I'm not quite sure. Also, if mathematically there is a better way t do that line, what would it be? Thanks so much for the help!

```
    s=""\
    "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"\
    "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"\
    "858615670789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"\
    "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"\
    "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"\
    "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"\
    "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"\
    "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"\
    "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"\
    "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"\
    "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"\
    "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"\
    "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"\
    "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"\
    "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"\
    "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"\
    "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"\
    "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"\
    "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"\
    "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"


    def findMaxProduct(n):
        """
        >>> findMaxProduct(1)
        9
        >>> findMaxProduct(2)
        81
        >>> findMaxProduct(22)
        3556892570112000
        >>> findMaxProduct(60)
        130883609235662685781298144870400000000
        >>> findMaxProduct(70)
        2412446685431734624320887406251212800000000
        >>> findMaxProduct(80)
        2412446685431734624320887406251212800000000
        """
        largest = 0
        for digit in range(len(s)-n):
                    product = 1
            for k in range (n):
             ###product = product * int(s(digit + k))
                if product > largest:
                    largest = product
        return largest
```

Comment: Is this Python? If so, please clarify and tag it so.

Comment: Aside: to avoid all those backslashes, you can take advantage of string literal concatentation and write `s = ("123" [return] "456" [return] "789")`, which will set `s` to "123456789".  Alternatively, you can simply write `s = """123 [return] 456 [return] 789"""` and then `s = ''.join(s.split())` or something.  That way you can avoid having to worry about whitespace or putting in quotation marks, which makes copying and pasting easier.

Answer (score 2):

You have `s(...)` which attempts to call a function named `s`. What you want instead is `s[...]` which will index into the string and return a subset of it.